# Iterating through list and popping number

Tags: python, list, loops, iterator

I have to ask the user to input a number and if it is in the list, then I have to pop it out of the list. I am still new to Python and this is what I have so far:

Any feedback is appreciated. The problem is that the number I input is not removed and when I input a number that is not on the list, multiple "Number not found" messages print out instead of just one.

```
numbersList = [-11, -4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 19]
numInput = input("Enter a number: ")
for item in range(len(numbersList)):
    if item == numInput:
        numbersList.pop(item)
        print(numbersList)
    
    else:
        print("Number not found.")
```

Comment: It looks like `item` is effectively an index, while `numInput` is a value. e.g. `item` with that `numbersList` will be 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 6. Entering 0 for `numInput` would drop -11 from `numbersList`. Should `item` be looping through the values of `numbersList` instead?

Comment: yes, that's what I am trying to do, to look for the `numInput` in `numbersList ` and popping that number out of the list if it is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you check every element for your number, hence the reason for the multiple messages.

Simply check if the number is in the list once:

```
numbersList = [-11, -4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 19]
numInput = int(input("Enter a number: "))
if numInput in numbersList
        numbersList.pop(numbersList.index(numInput))
        print(numbersList)
    
else:
    print("Number not found.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! But, whenever I run this, I keep getting "Number not found" even when the number I enter is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're iterating over the indexes of the array, not the values of the array.
2. At every iteration, if the conditional isn't met, you run the print Number not found.

Answer (score 0):

Is this good for you?

```
numbersList = [-11, -4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 19]

numInput = input("Enter a number: ")

if str(numInput) in str(numbersList):
    numbersList.remove(numInput)
    print(numInput)
else:
    print("Number not found.")
```

You could check really quickly if an item is in a list with the `in` keywords.
To remove the item, just use the `.remove(item_to_remove)` method.

Comment: I tried to run this, but I keep getting "Number not found."

Comment: Excuse me, the type didn't mach, I edit my aswer. You could change `str()` by `int()` or `float()`. However I choose `str()` in case of the user chose to type *six* for example. So there is no bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbersList = [-11, -4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 19]
numInput = input("Enter a number: ")
try:
   index = numbersList.index(int(numInput))
   print("Number found.")
   numbersList.pop(index)
except ValueError:
   print("Number not found.")
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! What does "try" and "except ValueError" do here?

Comment: Because the index function raise ValueError if the value doesn't exist in the list

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Please do edit your answer and add details to explain how and why this works and solves the problem.